# What is the seventh clan?

Tags: k-project

In the first season of *K*, we're introduced to the red, blue, and colorless clans early on, and later on are told about the silver and gold clans. In the movie, we come to know of the green clan.

But there are seven clans, and that only amounts to six. What is the color (or non-color?) of the seventh clan?

Answer (score 1):

From the first to last clans, they are White Rice Party, Tokijikuin, Homra, Scepter 4, Jungle, Cathedral, and Colorless. Cathedral was COMPLETELY destroyed in the kagutsu crater incident, therefore the only one in the series that has any resemblance to the powers of the Gray clan, is the Gray King Seigo Ootori. (Tenkei Iwafune) And any sort of information given on Cathedral is little to null on even the Wikipedia, other than the interesting insignia of their clan.

Answer (score 0):

actually it is the Grey clan.

silver, gold, green, red, blue, colorless, and grey. as Tenkei Iwafune is the 6th King, The Grey king.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is the brown clan.
because in the chamber slates at Mihashira tower you see the colors of the 6 known clans and the brown color
http://k-project.wikia.com/wiki/Mihashira_Tower?file=Dresden_Slate_Room.png

Comment: it seems like it is grey

Answer (score -1):

The first season is an introduction to the Silver, Gold, Red, Blue and Colorless clans and only mentions the Green clan. The movie K: Missing Kings introduced the Green clan, and the second season K: Return of Kings finally introduces the Grey Clan, a clan devastated by the Kagutsu Crater Incident. The only surviving member was the Grey King Seigo Ootori, which rescued the Green King and went into hiding, until the Green Kings plan to steal the Slate finally came.